# How to create a sqlite trigger that output results to file or stdout?

Tags: sqlite, triggers, output, tail

I have a database that is constantly being updated. I want a trigger that will look at the new updates on a column for a certain string, and output the row to stdout or a file when a match is found. This code just seems to create a blank output file that never gets updated.

```
.headers on
.mode csv
.output test.csv
CREATE TRIGGER watchString 
AFTER INSERT ON mytable
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE NEW.mycolumn LIKE '%mystring%';
END;
```